# Where does a staged Play 2.1 application look to find configuration files?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I recently ran into a surprising fact after staging my Play 2 project. I had two configuration files, **application.conf**, and **prod.conf** which get placed into **target/scala-2.10/staged/classes/** when I stage the application. When I call **./start -Dconfig.resource=application.conf** or **./start -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf**, the application starts up with the specified configuration files. But when I delete both the configuration files from **target/scala-2.10/staged/classes/**, the application still starts!

For this reason, I think these configuration files must be baked into the application elsewhere. Where is the application actually looking in order to find the configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the folder target/staged are all JARs play uses including the JAR of your web application with the configuration files.